# Architecture - What pattern seems this architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, layer, infrastructure

"application layer" (contains the request **controller**), and instantiates the "infrastructure layer classes" (responsable of the database accessors), then instantiates the "domain logic layer services", injecting the last mentioned infrastructure classes.

So the domain logic is agnostic to how database is being accessing, because the responsible classes are injected.

The application layer, serves the final response, example:

```
## router dispatch to this controller function
def mycontroller(price):
    product_repository = infrastructure_layer.mysql_product_repository()
    products = domain_layer.get_all_products(price, product_repository)
    return JsonResponse(products.to_string()) ## framework returns the response to the client
```

which kind of architecture seems this? is onion architecture, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I doesn't really have a name. I would go with "rails-like". Geared towards prototyping, since it exposes domain logic and persistence abstraction directly to presentation layer.

Comment: @tereško, have you any link of this?